# read and save local file on actionscript3 ios

Tags: ios, actionscript-3

any code about read and save local file actionscript3 ios

I'm not beginner in actionscript3 but i'm bgnr in iOS developing

any code

Answer (score 0):

Code to save a file

```
var imgFile : File= File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath(<file name>);
var stream: FileStream = new FileStream();
stream.open( imgFile, FileMode.WRITE);
stream.writeBytes( encodedContent, 0, encodedContent.length );  //encodedContent is byte array to save in afile
stream.close();
```

code to read a file

```
var imgFile : File= File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath(<file name>);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try using cache to save the SWF file itself, unless you want to save files WITHIN the SWF.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).